# Is it possible to prevent images resizing when rotating a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have the viewport set as follows:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Images appear at a nice size when the phone is in portrait mode.
As soon as I adjust it to landscape mode, the images and text increase in size.

Anyway I can prevent this from happening?  I don't mind if the text increases in size. I just don't want images to increase in size as they don't look great.

Note: I want to allow people to rotate their devices.

TIA

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140656/how-to-set-the-image-size-same-for-portrait-and-landscap-screen-orientation-in-j

Comment: instead of scaling you could make it responsive